# Laravel 5 check if object exists and use if true

Tags: php, laravel, object, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Instead of having to write:

```
{{$x = $data->where('colour_id', 1)->where('size_id', 1)->where('product_id', 1)->first() ? $data->where('colour_id', 1)->where('size_id', 1)->where('product_id', 1)->first()->quantity : 0}}
```

Is there a much cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Blade's `or` syntax:

```
{{ $data->where('colour_id', 1)->where('size_id', 1)->where('product_id', 1)->first->quantity or 0 }}
```

Not sure why you're assigning it to `$x` so I removed it, just readd if you do need it.

Personally, though, I'd make it a method on whatever model the `$data` object is an instance of. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing - you should not load data inside Blade.

In controller you should do:

```
$product = $data->where('colour_id', 1)->where('size_id', 1)->where('product_id', 1)->first();

return view('sample.blade.php', compact('product'));
```

And now in your Blade file

```
{{ $product ? $product->quantity : 0 }}
```

Comment: I can't do it that way because the view is static.

Answer (score 1):

For L5.1 there's [pluck()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_pluck):

```
{{ (int)$data->where(…)->pluck('quantity') }}
```

For L5.2 there's [value()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_value):

```
{{ (int)$data->where(…)->value('quantity') }}
```

Comment: @limnote This give me: Method value does not exist. (View: C:\wamp\www\brabiz\resources\views\stock-sheet-1.blade.php)